# send parameters from django updateview to model form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

in function based view it's easy to pass parameters to form instances as `form = FormName(user_id=..)` and do other staffs, but I'm wondering how to do this in django **update view** It's my **view**

```
class MedicalrecordUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MedicalRecords
    form_class = EditMedicalRecord
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "medicalrecord/edit_medicalrecord.html"
 
    # ?? no idea how to pass user id to EditMedicalRecord form
```

`forms.py`

```
class EditMedicalRecord(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop("user_id")
        super(EditMedicalRecord, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MedicalrecordUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MedicalRecords
    form_class = EditMedicalRecord
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "medicalrecord/edit_medicalrecord.html"
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user_id': self.kwargs.get('user_id')}) # self.kwargs is the kwargs passed to the view
        return kwargs
```

Comment: it it possiable to send `request.user` in `get_form_kwargs`?

Comment: @AliAref `self.request` will get you the request in class based views. So you would get `request.user` by writing `self.request.user`